# Can ADB debugging make XAPK downloads possible?

Tags: debian, apt, source, etc

I have just got the adb debugging method started on my chrome os for an alternate developer mode approach. However, I noticed that apks are starting to transfer into XAPKS which are a somewhat different file type. Can ADB debugging cover this too, or is there a specific install method for it?
Linux Debian 10 buster

Comment: by transfer I mean that there are less and less apks but more XAPKS and eventually it will only be XAPKS